# WPF, Binding not working even with property changed implemented

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm running into a problem binding to a '**StatusBarItem**'. I'll add that I'm using '**PropertyChanged.Fody**' to implement my models where I want changes to be raised.

Heres the 'XAML' snippet:

```
<StatusBar Grid.Row="2"
           Background="Transparent"
           Padding="5,0">
    <StatusBarItem Content="{Binding Path=Application.Status, Source={x:Static m:Locator.Instance}}"/>
</StatusBar>
```

Base Model:

```
[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
public class IModel {
}
```

Application Model:

```
public sealed class ApplicationModel : IModel {

    static ApplicationModel() {
        Instance = new ApplicationModel() {
            Status = "Ready"
        };
    }
    public static ApplicationModel Instance {
        get;
    }

    public string Status {
        get;
        set;
    }

}
```

Locater Model:

```
public sealed class Locator : IModel {

    static Locator() {
        Instance = new Locator();
    }
    public static Locator Instance {
        get;
    }

    public ApplicationModel Application => ApplicationModel.Instance;

}
```

When I want to change '**Status**' from anywhere in code, I do so like:

```
Locator.Instance.Application.Status = message;
```

Now my problem isn't that '**Status**' wont change, it changes just fine. When the application runs, it updates the **XAML** once with the default value set in **ApplicationModel**. It's the **XAML not updating to the new changes** once I set a new value. I feel I've done everything right as I'm using my '**BaseModel**' in other places without problems.

Comment: Does it bind correctly if you are using `ApplicationModel.Instance.Status` without the locator?

Comment: @RonBeyer No, doing that also fails to update.

Comment: Try decorating the `ApplicationModel` class with the Fody attribute, it may not be inherited.

Comment: @RonBeyer Before you said that, I was thinking about trying it. It didnt work.

Comment: Last thing I would try is to just implement INotifyPropertyChanged, maybe Fody is just mucking the whole thing up...

Comment: @RonBeyer Fixed, see comment. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED:**
I removed the '**PropertyChanged.Fody**' package along with '**FodyWeavers.xml**' then re-added them after deleting both '**\bin**' and '**\obj**' and finally a solution clean.